# map does not expand to full size on load when using jquery mobile

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, dictionary, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map on a page that uses jQuery mobile.  I experience a similar problem if I swap in a Google Map instead of Leaflet, so I don't believe this to be specific to Leaflet but rather to jQuery mobile.

The problem is that when it first loads, the background imagery of the map does not expand to fit the size of the div that contains it.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lxotwbrk/2/

See that the red border is the correct size, but the map imagery is missing in the grey area.  Note that as soon as you adjust the height or width of the result window on the jsfiddle page (or the full browser window if running on localhost), the background imagery immediately fills the canvas.

I have perused and tried suggestions from similar threads but haven't had luck.  If I put the map on a page without JQM, I don't have this issue.

Here is the code.  Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>no title needed</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
      type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>   

    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

      /*this holds the map canvas*/
      .ui-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(event, ui) {
        var map = new L.Map('map-canvas', {
          center: [42.3, -71],
          zoom: 7
        });

        L.tileLayer('http://tiles1-4001b3692e229e3215c9b7a73e528198.skobblermaps.com/TileService/tiles/2.0/00021210101/0/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: 'Skobbler'
        }).addTo(map);


      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-url="map-page" data-role="page" id="map-page" data-title="JQM's title">      
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </div><!-- /content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #map-canvas is wrapped with div's. They must all allow to expand the height to 100%.

Correct your JSFiddle with this ...

```
html, body, #map-page, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

Comment: you are correct - it was the `map-page` div that I had neglected to have at 100% height.  I've been tripped up by a similar problem before - I seem to forget that divs need all of their containers to have height specified.  For anyone else who wants to see the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxotwbrk/6/

Comment: Out of curiosity - why does this correct itself on browser resize?